# Custom Search API shows nothing Google will

Tags: json, api, search, google-custom-search

Why google shows me search results for: 4250859801761 (it is a barcode)
but the custom search api shows nothing...
Search in entire web is on.

```
    "request": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - 4250859801761",
    "totalResults": "0",
    "searchTerms": "4250859801761",
    "count": 10,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve"
   }
  ]
 },
 "searchInformation": {
  "searchTime": 0.519547,
  "formattedSearchTime": "0.52",
  "totalResults": "0",
  "formattedTotalResults": "0"
 }
}
```